# Get "next" row from SQL Server database and flag it in single transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, queue

I have a SQL Server table that I'm using as a queue, and it's being processed by a multi-threaded (and soon to be multi-server) application. I'd like a way for a process to claim the next row from the queue, flagging it as "in-process", without the possibility that multiple threads (or multiple servers) will claim the same row at the same time.

Is there a way to update a flag in a row and retrieve that row at the same time? I want something like this psuedocode, but ideally, without blocking the whole table:

```
Block the table to prevent others from reading
Grab the next ID in the queue
Update the row of that item with a "claimed" flag (or whatever)
Release the lock and let other threads repeat the process
```

What's the best way to use T-SQL to accomplish this? I remember seeing a statement one time that would DELETE rows and, at the same time, deposit the DELETED rows into a temp table so you could do something else with them, but I can't for the life of me find it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OUTPUT clause

```
UPDATE myTable SET flag = 1
WHERE
id = 1
AND 
flag <> 1
OUTPUT DELETED.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Main thing is to use a combination of table hints as shown below, within a transaction.

```
DECLARE @NextId INTEGER
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 1 @NextId = ID
FROM QueueTable WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST)
WHERE BeingProcessed = 0
ORDER BY ID ASC

IF (@NextId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE QueueTable
        SET BeingProcessed = 1
        WHERE ID = @NextID
    END

COMMIT TRANSACTION

IF (@NextId IS NOT NULL)     
    SELECT * FROM QueueTable WHERE ID = @NextId
```

`UPDLOCK` will lock the next available row it finds that's available, preventing other processes from grabbing it.
`ROWLOCK` will ensure only the individual row is locked (I've never found it to be a problem not using this as I think it will only use a rowlock anyway, but safest to use it). 
`READPAST` will prevent a process being blocked, waiting for another to finish.

Comment: +1, what I was thinking, but you answered faster!  I'd add that `READPAST` allows another process to not wait until you unlock this row, it can skip this locked row and keep scanning for a row where `BeingProcessed = 0`

Comment: @KM - it's one of things I keep meaning to blog about, so it's very fresh on my mind at the mo! I *will* get round to it....at some point!

Comment: The OUTPUT clause (from the other answer) is what I was originally considering, but had forgotten the name of. Does this method offer some benefit over that clause, or does the clause just replicate what you've built here?

Comment: @rwmnau - the main difference is that this answer allows you to do more processing within the transaction - however, if you don't need to do anything else in the transaction then the OUTPUT clause should be fine if you're using SQL Server 2005 or later (which I presume you are!)